# pkt-line 3: invalid capabilities - GitRob

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-api

I've been trying to install GitRob on Linux. I've completed all the steps. However, once I try to clone the repo's for the security scan, the following error occurs:

`Error cloning repository M365DSC: pkt-line 3: invalid capabilities: arguments not allowed (multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed allow-tip-sha1-in-want allow-reachable-sha1-in-want no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/main filter object-format=sha1 agent=git/github-1c5ee477c782)

Maybe, there's an GitHub API permissions issue but here is my permissions for my API that GitRob uses:

[API Perm] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Weri.png)

Tried googling. I've tried creating new instance and starting the installation again.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)